# How do I handle setting multiple styles (due to vendor prefixes) in CSS with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, vendor-prefix

I want the user to click a button to reveal a hidden flexbox menu. So of course I know how to handle the normal stuff:

```css
nav#test {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('#test').style.display = 'flex';
```

But what about the stupid vendor-prefix alternate rules? That's never come up for me before and I don't know how to handle them.

**EDIT : Why not Autoprefixer?**

In a word: `wrap`. In the above example, I used `flex-flow: column nowrap;`. But let's say the rule had been `flex-flow: row wrap;`. Autoprefixer would only give you a fix for very recent browsers, because there isn't one (no `wrap` support) on older (but not even *that* old) Firefox and Safari [which includes Chrome for iOS].

So, if you used Autoprefixer, your `flex-flow: row wrap` element would simply break on such browsers. Depending on settings your flex children might run right off the side of the screen.

Maybe you'd rather offer an alternate layout in these cases by specifying `-webkit-box-orient: vertical` and perhaps even `-moz-box-orient: vertical` (the equivalents to the modern `flex-direction: column`).

Comment: Create a CSS class with all those properties and just add it to the element you want on click, instead.

Comment: Very simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerH you should break that out in to an answer so he can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a CSS class selector with the standard property and prefixed properties and simply use JavaScript to add the class to whatever element you need on a button click. For example:

```js
var navButton = document.getElementById("navControl");
navButton.addEventListener("click", showNav, false);

function showNav() {
    var nav = document.getElementById("test");
    nav.className = "flexClass";
}
```

```css
nav#test {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

#test.flexClass {
    display: flex; /* Standard for Firefox, Chrome, and Opera */
    display: -webkit-box;  /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -ms-flexbox;  /* IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /*  Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+ */
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="navControl">Show Nav menu</button>
<nav id="test">Nav menu goes here</nav>
```

I wrote `#test.flexClass` instead of just `.flexClass` because ID selectors are more specific than class selectors, so `.flexClass` alone would have been overridden by your existing `nav#test` selector.

Comment: Thanks! In my case `nav#test` was just for purposes of the question and I'm not using an ID on my `nav` at all, but I think most people are probably going to have multiple `nav` tags and have to use IDs, so that's a useful caveat I'm glad you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) will automatically add vendor prefixes to any properties that need it.

Comment: I wanted to leave a note for future people researching this issue on why I didn't select this answer.

For most things, Autoprefixer is probably the most efficient answer. Flexbox, however, requires a little more custom intervention. See my edit to the question for more.